# Event Made Easy - Block registration to two or more events that have the same category

Tags: plugins, functions, plugin-list-category-post

I really need help, I have tried several ways **The rule is: The user can not register for another event that has the same category defined. In other words, the user has registered for event '1' which has category 'A' the user wants to register for event '2' which also has the same category 'A'- he should be prevented from being able to register in event '2.**  I tried blocking by Category, I tried by Location, I even tried by custom field, if the event has the custom field id on the form it blocks the registration if the user has already registered in another event that has the same custom field. What I managed so far was to block by event ID, but my events are not fixed in the code, they always change and it would be impractical to make changes in functions.php to keep changing the event id all the time. That's why I thought of something easier, the best would be to limit by category.

I tried to contact the developer, but he doesn't support this kind of request because he would have to do it via code and he doesn't have time to do it for free or provide a snippet. So, I ask for help from the coelgas if someone can help me. The plugin is here: https://github.com/liedekef/events-made-easy

The only code I could get to work was the event id blocking, but that, as I said is no longer useful to me, since I won't have control over the number of event ids that should be blocked. But blocking by category would be ideal:

```
add_filter('eme_eval_booking_form_post_filter','do_my_stuff');
function do_my_stuff($event) {
$already_registered = false;
$event_ids = array(6, 7, 8, 9);

// get the current user
$booker = eme_get_person_by_post();

if (!empty($booker)) {
    // check if the user has already registered for one of the events
    foreach ($event_ids as $event_id) {
        if (!empty(eme_get_booking_ids_by_person_event_id($booker['person_id'], $event_id))) {
            $already_registered = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // check if the event is in the allowed event IDs
    if (in_array($event['event_id'], $event_ids)) {
        // if the user has already registered for one of the events, show an error message
        if ($already_registered) {
            return array(0 => 0, 1 => 'Você já realizou um agendamento desta etapa');
        }
    }
}

// if the user has not registered for any of the events, allow the registration
return array(0 => 1, 1 => '');
 }
```

As I couldn't get anything by category. I tried blocking using the name of the events, because in the plugin the event can contain the same title what changes is just the slug. So I followed the path of the code that worked for me but instead of using ID I used the event name which in this case is "Entrevista Devolutiva". But without success, see the code:

```
add_filter('eme_eval_booking_form_post_filter','do_my_stuff');
function do_my_stuff($event) {
    $already_registered = false;
    $event_names = array('Entrevista Devolutiva');

    // get the current user
    $booker = eme_get_person_by_post();

    if (!empty($booker)) {
        // check if the user has already registered for one of the events
        foreach ($event_names as $event_name) {
            if (!empty(eme_get_booking_ids_by_person_event_name($booker['person_id'], $event_name))) {
                $already_registered = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // check if the event is in the allowed event names
        if (in_array($event['event_name'], $event_names)) {
            // if the user has already registered for one of the events, show an error message
            if ($already_registered) {
                return array(0 => 0, 1 => 'Você já realizou um agendamento desta etapa');
            }
        }
    }

    // if the user has not registered for any of the events, allow the registration
    return array(0 => 1, 1 => '');
}
```